# dev mode in Eclipse OSGI run configuration

Tags: eclipse, osgi

I'm having some problems in a small OSGI project.
In one of the bundles I install and start another bundle programmatically that wasn't installed before.

Nevertheless, when I run the project in Eclipse, jumps a `ClassNotFoundException` in the implementation of the bundle.

I believe it's because Eclipse automatically starts the project with a -dev parameter (development mode) pointing at dev.properties file where it specifies the bin folder where it builds each bundle. Obviously this dev.properties file created by Eclipse doesn't include the bundle I'll install later.

The project works fine outside of Eclipse and the jars are correct but when I run it within Eclipse a ClassNotFoundException jumps. This happens because when I start eclipse in dev mode a dev.properties file is created to enhance the classpath of the framework. But then, when I want to install new bundles the dev.properties doesn't update when a new event occurs and also Eclipse doesn't let me use my customized dev.properties file so the framework can't load classes from that new bundle.

Is there any way to use a customized dev.properties or to change anything that can make this work in eclipse?

Here is a small example of the code:

```
 public void charge(String location){
    try {
        System.out.println("Entró");
        bundle2= bundleContext.installBundle(location);
        System.out.println("Instalado");

        bundle2.start();
        System.out.println("Activado");

    } catch (BundleException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question pointed my attention to the osgi.dev property (and the -dev option) which I didn't know. I had the opposite problem, that I am launching OSGi programmatically from a plain Java program and wanted to start a bundle right directly from its project location in Eclipse (during development) without packaging a jar, but OSGi could not find the bundle's classes -- that is not until I learnt about the osgi.dev property.

Answer (score 2):

When you launch an Equinox framework instance from within Eclipse using PDE then the "dev" mode is used to enhance the classpath of the framework to load classes and resources from the "bin" folder within a plug-in project.

If something works when running from within Eclipse but does not work when exported/built and run externally than it's likely that something is missing in the build.properties file (if any of the PDE export functionality is used) or that some package imports are missing in the MANIFEST.MF.

Can you provide more details on the setup and how you produce the bits that you run outside of Eclipse?

Comment: The project works fine outside of Eclipse and the jars are correct but when I run it within Eclipse a ClassNotFoundException jumps. This happens because when I start eclipse in dev mode a dev.properties file is created to enhance the classpath of the framework. But then, when I want to install new bundles the dev.properties doesn't update when a new event occurs and also Eclipse doesn't let me use my customized dev.properties file so the framework can't load classes from that new bundle.

Is there any way to use a custom dev.properties or to change anything that can make this work in eclipse?

Comment: Here is a small example of the code:

 public void charge(String location){
    try {
        System.out.println("Entró");
        bundle2= bundleContext.installBundle(location);
        System.out.println("Instalado");

        bundle2.start();
        System.out.println("Activado");

    } catch (BundleException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
Thanks

Elena

Comment: Please post follow up questions as new questions. It's hard to follow in comments. But it looks like this requires an enhancement in the launch configuration implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the dev.properties is meant to be used like that, but in any case, OSGi is dynamic, if you install a bundle, it should work, regardless of -dev mode.

Could it be that the jar or folder you're installing from is incorrect? I suggest you export the bundle you're installing from eclipse (From the project -> Export -> Deployable Plugins).

If your build.properties is correct, you should get a correct jar. Try installing that jar.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Debug Configuration-> OSGi Framework. Make sure those options are checked:

- `Include optional dependencies when computing required bundles`       and
- `Add new workspace bundles to this launch configuration automatically`.

This way every time you add or create a new plugin inside your workspace it is added to the execution.